# How to post JSON data and a request token(in the header) in cURL php

Tags: php, azure, curl

I want to send the login credentials and a pin number as a JSON data and the request token as my http header.

initially it's like this,

```
{
    "Username":"admin",
    "Password":"root123",
   "PinCode” : "hello321"
}
```

and I need to post my **Request Header token** as well.

and if the request is ok, I should get JSON response as follow,

```
{
            "Title": "Mr.",
            "Name": "Pushkov",
            "Age": "18"

}
```

I'm trying to do it in cURL PHP. Below is my controller code.

I tried to save my request token to a variable and pass it in header and post username, password and pinnumber as JSON data. if the login success than user info should be displayed. but I'm struggling to move ahead from here. How can I achieve that?

```
public function send_data() {

$url='http://samplesite.azurewebsites.net/api/member/loginmember';

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/main');


$data = array("Username" =>$this->input->post('un'), "Password"  =>$this->input->post('pw'), "PinCode" =>$this->input->post('PinCode'));                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);   


//echo $data_string; 

// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
); 
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);


//var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
$data2=json_decode($result, true);
$ref_id = ( ( is_array( $data2["UserCode"] ) ? implode(", ", $data2["PinCode"]) : $data2["RequestToken"] ) ); // array to string
$acc_t = $data2["RequestToken"];
$uun = $data2["UserCode"];

//echo $acc_t;


// Closing
curl_close($ch);
//print  $result ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you set a URL to `curl_init()` and you also passed another one in `CURLOPT_URL` option. You can't do that in one cURL request.

If you are using OAuth 2.0 you can set the access token to `CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER` option.

More information, please refer to [PHP manual on cURL Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).